# Font Awesome Icons not showing in Chrome with Bootstrap

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

For some reason, Font Awesome Icons are not showing in Chrome, but they work in Firefox.

I've tried changing the CDN but doesn't work either. The problem shows up when I add the nav-link class to the links with the icons. When the links are without the class they show no problem.

```
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="work.html" class="nav-link">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item social-links">
        <a
          href="#"
          target="_blank"
          class="nav-link social-link"
          ><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></i
        ></a>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="nav-link social-link"
          target="_blank"
          ><i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i
        ></a>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="nav-link social-link"
          ><i class="far fa-envelope fa-3x"></i
        ></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/od3rm9 here is a SS side by side chrome and firefox, the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use CDN files. download the files from fontawosome site "https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself". and import below links in your html file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">`

and don't forget to add "webfonts" folder in your template folder.

Comment: I did download it and copied into my project with @import because I'm using sass, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Download the complete .zip file from link "https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself". when you unzip the file you will get folder "webfonts". Add this folder in your project. because all icons comes from font file. that's why we need to add this folder like a fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right version of Font_Awesome and Bootstrap. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cw3zpf71/) with your example and works on Chrome:

[image]

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul class="menu-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About me</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="work.html" class="nav-link">My Work</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item social-links">
    <a
      href="#"
      target="_blank"
      class="nav-link social-link"
      ><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></i
    ></a>
    <a
      href="#"
      class="nav-link social-link"
      target="_blank"
      ><i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i
    ></a>
    <a
      href="#"
      class="nav-link social-link"
      ><i class="far fa-envelope fa-3x"></i
    ></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm using Sass, can that be the problem ? I am not using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with Font Awesome 5 and bootstrap 4.3. It did not work altogether to actually display an icon. I have read many threads and solutions given on StackOverflow and other places, nothing worked for me.

My workaround: using version 4.7 (icon names don't have the "alt" parts, but icons are more or less there none the less) - categories are also therefore `fa` and not `fas`.

This is the CSS linking I used at the top of my page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and the CSS code: (don't ask me about the version there, it works anyways, and is all I could find as a solution - I got a hard time returning good search results that went in depth on the topic and also consulted some documentation at Font Awesome.)

```
.fa {
display: inline-block;
font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-weight: 900; 
color:lightpink;
```